# Can we filter data when bind dropdown with model data in asp-net MVC razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to load few selected model based `item.StateID` in a dropdown. So I did it with the below code but I'm getting an error. I am talking about this line `Model.Cities.SelectMany(x => x.StateID == item.StateID)`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCityId, new SelectList(
Model.Cities.SelectMany(x => x.StateID == item.StateID), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCityId = item.CityID), "-- Select City--", 
new { id = "cboCity", @class = "edit-mode" })
```

Can't we populate dropdown this way? If I made mistake in code then guide me with a new rectified code sample.

Comment: Model.Cities.SelectMany(x => x.StateID == item.StateID)? Did you mean Model.Cities.where(x => x.StateID == item.StateID)?

Comment: @tmg thanks a lot for your correction :)

Comment: is there good site which help me to learn all this SelectMany(), select() and many more. what keyword i should use to search google. thanks

Comment: search for "linq" as the tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well what you want...I hope yes! :-)

Maybe this will work for you...It is what i use and it is working for me.

In the Controller:

```
var list = (from x in db.Cities
                            where
                                x.StateID == item.StateID
                            select x)ToList();
list.Add(new City { SelectedCityId = 0, Nombre = "-- Select City--" });
list = list.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.SelectedCityId = new SelectList(list, "SelectedCityId", "Name");
```

In the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCityId, htmlAttributes: new {      @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SelectedCityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Maybe you have to change the name of the model and / or the fields i put in my code...
And the declaration for db, should be something like this:

```
YourContext db = new YourContext();
```

I hope it helps!